# How do you get a p-value for each group in a column?

Tags: r, statistics, p-value, chi-squared

I have a test that returns the p-value result of a column, in association to a positive or negative column. But I need to see what each of the four possible groups (values) in the column have a p-value of.

My two columns are categorical, and look a bit like this:

```
  acidic          status
__________________________
grapefruit       positive
orange           negative
lemon            positive
grapefruit       negative
lime             positive
orange           negative
grapefruit       positive
```

And i want to get my results to show individually like this:

```
    Pearsons Chi-squared test

data:  fruit
                  pvalue
orange            0.254
grapefruit        0.191
lemon             0.082
lime              0.022
```

as opposed to this what I get, overall pvalue:

```
    Pearsons Chi-squared test

data:  fruit
X-squared = 4.7907, df = 3, p-value = 0.1878
```

this is what I have:

```
fruit <- table(mtrx[,13],mtrx[,12])
fruit
chisq.test(fruit, simulate.p.value = FALSE)
```

I wanted something a bit like a contingency table, but to display the p-value, instead of the counts. I've seen this done before in a regression model and I know it will have a similar principle, but not sure how to get it.

Comment: You need to provide some useable data. Use `dput` to put it in a format we can use and paste it into your question. Something like `dput(head(mtrx[, 12:13], 25))`. Or make up some data. Your code is for a 2-way table with fruit and status so you will get one p-value. If you want p-values for each fruit separately you will need to run chi square on each fruit although a simple binomial test would probably be better since you null hypothesis is the the number of positive cases will be equal to the number of negative cases.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to test is not very clear, what you testing with the chi-square is whether there is any association between the labels, so one way you can test each fruit label is by treating the others as 1 category, for example:

```
set.seed(111)
mtrx = data.frame(acidic = sample(c("lemon","orange","lime"),100,replace=TRUE),
status = sample(c("positive","negative"),100,replace=TRUE))

res = lapply(unique(mtrx$acidic),function(i){
       ctest = chisq.test(table(mtrx$acidic == i,mtrx$status))
       data.frame(fruit = i, pvalue = ctest$p.value)
       })

res = do.call(rbind,res)
res
 
   fruit    pvalue
1 orange 0.5126908
2   lime 0.0536863
3  lemon 0.3029598
```

The regression method can work if your null hypothesis is that the `status` is distributed 1:1 (0.5 positive 0.5 negative) and you want to test whether any of the fruit deviate from that:

```
summary(glm(status ~ 0 + acidic,data=mtrx,family=binomial))

Call:
glm(formula = status ~ 0 + acidic, family = binomial, data = mtrx)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.31529  -1.29325   0.06384   1.06582   1.46140  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
acidiclemon    0.3185     0.3286   0.969   0.3324  
acidiclime    -0.6466     0.3722  -1.737   0.0823 .
acidicorange   0.2683     0.3684   0.728   0.4665
```